# Suppress file already exists on android OS

Tags: android

is there a way to suppress on any  browser in android the prompt the comes up if you are downloading a file that carries the same name as a file already on the phone

so basically i want to overwrite it  , there is a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-overwrite-alrea/lddjgfpjnifpeondafidennlcfagekbp)on Pc that does that  , is there something similar for android ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, because the browser is its own app.  It might be chrome, or firefox, or any number of others,  You'd need to override it on each, and there's no API to do so, so you'd need the user to install the appropriate plugin to each (if it even exists).

Although to demonstrate the point-  I have no idea what prompt you're talking about, because I've never seen it.  Every browser I've ever used on Android merely downloads a new copy and places a (1), (2), etc at the end without prompting.